# Concatenate id in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have the following html:

```
<div id="myDiv1_" class="formElement1"><asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" CssClass="formInput1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></div><br />
<div id="myDiv2_" class="formElement1"><asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" CssClass="formInput1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></div><br />
<div id="myDiv3_" class="formElement1"><asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" CssClass="formInput1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></div>
```

And I have the following jQuery code:

```
$('input[type="text"]').focus(function () {
    $(this).addClass("formElement1");
});

$('input[type="text"]').blur(function () {
    $(this).removeClass("formElement1");
});
```

What I am trying to do is when the input box has focus I want to change class for the div.  I am trying to change the `$(this).addClass` to use something like `$('#' + div_id + textbox_id').addClass`.

However, being somewhat new to jQuery, I am not sure how to accomplsh this.  Any help is appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the class of the parent div, use:

```
$('input[type="text"]').focus(function () {
    $(this).closest('div').addClass("formElement1");
});

$('input[type="text"]').blur(function () {
    $(this).closest('div').removeClass("formElement1");
});
```

closest method will search up the dom (starting at this) for the first element that match

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a selector. Just traverse to the <s>nested</s> parent element.

```
$(this.parentNode).addClass('whatever');
```

If you absolutely want to do a DOM selection, you can grab the number from the ID, and use it in the nested ID.

```
var num = this.id.slice( -1 );
$('#myDiv' + num + '_').addClass('whatever');
```

---

**EDIT:** I had it reversed at first. I was thinking the handler was on the `<div>`. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

`$('#' + div_id +' > #'+ textbox_id').addClass("formElement1")` should work

Answer (score 1):

The IDs of each textbox are unique I assume so you can simply do it like this and there should be no ambiguity as to which element you are adding the class to:

```
$('input[type="text"]').focus(function () {
    $('#' + textbox_id).addClass("formElement1");
}
```

and if you only want to change the class only when the correct textbox receives focus:

```
$('#' + textbox_id).focus(function () {
    $('#' + textbox_id).addClass("formElement1");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try using [starts with](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) selector like so `$('div[id^=myDiv] input').focus(function(){$(this).addClass('focus');});` don't forget to `removeClass('focus')` on `blur()` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Get the parent of the textbox in the dom and apply the class to it (div in this case). You need to change your code as follows:

```
$('input[type="text"]').focus(function () {
     $(this).parent().addClass("your-class");;
});

$('input[type="text"]').blur(function () {
     $(this).parent().addClass("your-class");;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I gather, your inputs are inside (children-of) the div.  So, you'd want something like:

```
$('input[type="text"]').focus(function () {
    $(this).closest("div").addClass("formElement1");
});
```

That will find the closest parent div and add the appropriate class.

Also, if you're using ajax to do some replacement here, you might want to consider using `live()`:

```
$('input[type="text"]').live("focus", function () {
    $(this).closest("div").addClass("formElement1");
});
```